# Delphi - Installed components lost

Tags: delphi

a few days ago I've setup my dev environment (delphi 2009 on a VM with win 7 and a user on a domain), installed my components (jedi's, devExpress, ADS an so on).
Today I start my machine, opening delphi - and what must I see? Every installed componenet isn't there any more.
Could it be that there's something wrong with the domain user or so? 
The library pathes are completely empty (except the standard entries) - where does delphi store that information?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It sounds if you loged on with another account. The settings (including the library path) is stored in the registry, under HKEY_CURRENT_USER.

You can find your library path here: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\CodeGear\BDS\6.0\Library